# Slow booting with strange logo

Tags: boot, ubuntu-gnome, boot-time

I uninstall and later reinstall gnome on my Ubuntu 14.04. I then upgraded to ubuntu 15.04.  I am experiencing painfully slow loading,  thus after using grub to select ubuntu since I dual boot ubuntu with Windows 10, it takes about 2-3 minutes before the login screen shows up. 
Moreover,  this is the logo that shows up during this 2-3 minutes of loading. 
How can I speed the loading process.  And what does this image means?

Comment: Which image shows up?

Comment: Hi, how do I attach the image

Comment: In the editor Ctrl + G , then drag and drop (up to 2MB)

Comment: I am informed I need at least ten reputations to post images